# SVN: directory rename fails with "child not part of the commit"

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am trying to SVN-rename a big folder using TortoiseSVN. Was:

```
root
  folder A
    folder B
      file
```

Became:

```
root
  folder C
    folder B
      file
```

Now I am trying to commit and TortoiseSVN tells me that

> root\folderC\folderB is not under version control and is not part of the commit, yet its child root\folderC\folderB\file is part of the commit

The `svn status -v` shows: for folder A (i.e. `svn status folderA -v` executed in `root`):

```
D    folderA
D    folderA\folderB
D    folderA\folderB\file
```

and so on with `D` for all subfolders and files in folderA.

For folder B (`svn status folderB -v`):

```
A   +    -     folderB
    +    -     folderB\folderC
    +    -     folderB\folderC\file
```

I am quite lost. What puzzles me a lot is that TortoiseSVN shows all contents of folder C as up-to-date (green checkmarks), only folder B itself is shown with a plus overlay sign.

I've done updating, cleaning up and restarting the computer.

Comment: Show us the result of `svn status -v`.

Comment: @bahrep: Done, excluding the file sizes and user names.

Comment: Have you tried to commit from the root folder or from the renamed folder?

Comment: @splash: From the root folder, because otherwise the deletion of folderA is not committed.

Comment: Maybe you are doing better with renaming on the repository and a clean checkout.

Comment: @splash: Thanks for the workaround, it helped. I'd like to know though if it is a bug in TortoiseSVN (or SVN itself) or I am doing something wrong. I used this feature many times for a couple of items, but it's the first time I tried to move a whole subtree.